# Как перевести таблицу в массив js

Tags: javascript, массивы, xls

Есть таблица [таблица](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gt8zvvnqxmyvghc/need_file.xlsx?dl=0)

Это только её часть, как можно её перевести в массив вот такого типа?

```
    0: {
        0: 0,
        1: 4.5
        2: 2
        3: 2.75
        4: 3.1
        ﻿5: 2
        6: 3.1
        7: 4
        8: 3,9
        9: 3,45
        и так далее
    },
    1: {
        0: 4.5
        1: 0
        2: 2.5
        3: 1.75
        4: 1.4
        ﻿5: 2.5
        6: 1.4
        7: 1.3
        8: 1,2
        9: 1,05
        10: 1,05
        и так далее
    },
    2: {
        и так далее
    },
    3: {
```

Comment: А гугл на что? Курите https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx , к примеру.

Comment: выгрузите xls в csv и делайте что хотите

Comment: гугл вообще ничего внятного мне не сказал

Comment: @Sublihim а можно, если не трудно, поподробней написать ответ?

Comment: @reFactorPro, а, собственно, так ли важен язык, на котором будет написана обработка или важен результат? Т.к. если подумать, то еще проще написать обработку на VBA

Comment: @Sublihim объясните, что такое VBA?

Comment: @reFactorPro Visual Basic for Application